# MariaDB: temporary database and workaround for autocommit

Tags: php, database, mariadb, temporary, autocommit

I have a web page written in PHP (version 7.3.12), where an user can write any SQL statement and then execute it (I am using MariaDB version 10.4.10, included in XAMPP). When user writes DDL statements, most of them are unfortunately autocommited, hence there is no space for rollbacking a transaction. I don't want them to e.g. create 200 tables in a database that would wihtout any intervention persist in the database forever. **Is there a way to workaround this problem?**

Also I was wondering if besides temporary tables exists something like a **temporary database?** I was thinking about this, because if I could create some sort of a temporary database (that would be visible to session only), user can practically do anything without me worrying any leftovers would stay in the DB.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: This isn't really an appropriate site to brainstorm application design. But I would put each user in a virtual environment with a limited amount of disk space. If they try to create too many databases or tables they'll run out of space and get an error. You can automatically delete the virtual environment if it hasn't been used in a while.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data definition language (DDL) statements in MariaDB are not part of its transaction semantics, so there's no way to roll back DDL using `ROLLBACK`.

With the appropriate code in your php application, you can create a uuniquely named database for each user session, then drop it at the end of the session.  This is how the various database fiddle sites work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will definitely use this, easy and straightforward solution in my eyes! Accepting as answer, cannot upvote you though (not enough reputation) :/